# Import Error Qt core while packaging the project using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I am making exe file using pyinstaller, I am using the following command

```
pyinstaller main.py -F --name "AcrowAutoCalc" --clean --hidden-import=PyQt5.sip
```

But it seems that it failed to import PyQt5:

[image: error image]

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

edit adding minimal reproducible example

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMarginsF, QSizeF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPageLayout, QPageSize
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

root.title("Autocalculation sheet")
window_height = 650
window_width = 900
root.resizable(0, 0)
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x_cordinate = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
y_cordinate = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))
root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(window_width, window_height, x_cordinate, y_cordinate))

root.mainloop()
```

after converting it using pyinstaller it gave me import error

Comment: create a [example]